# Class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException Message No such property: list for class: gtunes.Album Possible solutions: id, class, dirty

Tags: grails

Album's index.gsp

---

It is giving error on line no. 5, the same code I am running in as .HTML file then it is working fine but in index.jsp error is coming I do not understand why it is happening.

> ```
>   <div class="container-fluid">
>       <h3><p class="text-center">Album list</p></h3>
>       <ul id="album" class="list-group">
>           <g:each var="album" in="${myvar}">
>               <button type="button" class="list-group-item" onClick="editalbum('${album.list}')">
>                   <span class="badge">${album.title}</span>
>               </button>
>           </g:each>
>       </ul>
>   </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

AlbumController.groovy
I have def abc which takes the album list and it render it to the index page

```
 package gtunes
    import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
    import grails.transaction.Transactional

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    class AlbumController {

        static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

        def index(Integer max) {
            def abc = Album.list(max:10);
            render(view:"index", model:[myvar:abc]);
            //params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
            //respond Album.list(params), model:[albumInstanceCount: Album.count()]
        }[Grails error][1]
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9gjSzsLSnClRFZVbWE1MWU0aDQ
here is the image of the error

Comment: Why do you have `${album.list}` in this line? There is no properly list on this object as error states. Do you want to use `list()` method instead of property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no list for the object 'album', you probably trying to edit that one instance of the object 'album', Try this and adjust your JS code accordingly:

```
onClick="editalbum('${album}')"
```

or by id e.g.:

```
onClick="editalbum('${album.id}')"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use null safe operator in your gsp:

   ${album?.list}
   in this case you'll become protected from errors when album is null
2. Put groovy code into double quotes

   "${album?.list}"
3. Check it. Your view must be .gsp

   > I am running in as .HTML file then it is working fine but in index.jsp
4. Is "list" a property of class Album? Looks like you need to pass here another property like 'id'. If you need list() of albums - you already have it in 'myvar'.